# sum pair of columns based on matching fields

Tags: text-processing, awk, sort, uniq

I have a large file in the following format:

```
2 1019 0 12 
2 1019 3 0 
2 1021 0 2 
2 1021 2 0 
2 1022 4 5
2 1030 0 1 
2 1030 5 0 
2 1031 4 4
```

If the values in *column 2* match, I want to sum the values in *column 3* and *4* of both lines, else just the sum of the values in the unique line.

So the output I am hoping for would look like this:

```
2 1019 15 
2 1021 4 
2 1022 9 
2 1030 6 
2 1031 8
```

I am able to sort files according to *column 2* with `awk` or `sort` and sum the last columns with `awk`, but only for individual lines not for two lines where *column 2* matches.

Comment: What about column 1?

Comment: @glennjackman: Column 1 has the same value throughout each file. It serves as an identifier for the file (I have 45 of those) and will be used for some downstream process. For my question it might as well be ignored (or deleted) and later added again.

Comment: or, make `$1 $2` as the key.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would do this in Perl:

```
$ perl -lane '$k{"$F[0] $F[1]"}+=$F[2]+$F[3]; 
              END{print "$_ $k{$_}" for keys(%k) }' file 
2 1019 15
2 1021 4
2 1030 6
2 1031 8
2 1022 9
```

Or awk:

```
awk '{a[$1" "$2]+=$3+$4}END{for (i in a){print i,a[i]}}' file
```

If you want the output sorted according to the second column you could just pipe to `sort`:

```
awk '{a[$1" "$2]+=$3+$4}END{for (i in a){print i,a[i]}}' file | sort -k2
```

---

Note that both solutions include the 1st column as well. The idea is to use the first and second columns as keys to a hash (in perl) or an associative array (in awk). The key in each solution is `column1 column2` so if two lines have the same column two but a different column one, they will be grouped separately:

```
$ cat file
2 1019 2 3
2 1019 4 1
3 1019 2 2

$ awk '{a[$1" "$2]+=$3+$4}END{for (i in a){print i,a[i]}}' file
3 1019 4
2 1019 10
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this could help, but is column 1 always 2 and does results depend on it?

```
awk '{ map[$2] += $3 + $4; } END { for (i in map) { print "2", i, map[i] | "sort -t't'" } }' file
```

or as mentioned by [glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman) in comments about sorting:

```
gawk '{ map[$2] += $3 + $4; } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"; for (i in map) { print 2, i, map[i] } }' file
```

Comment: If you have GNU awk, use `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"` instead of piping to `sort`. ref https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning

Comment: @taliezin: Thanks taliezin and terdon. Both approaches worked like a charm. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Curious: why did you decide to sort lexically, not numerically?

Comment: sorry I was in a hurry and failed...

Comment: @tompio - I think terdon's is better and as it posted sort is better to be numeric

Comment: @taliezin: As I said both worked for me, I marked the terdon answers as the "correct" one. I guess that's what you intended. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there also any easy way to include a count/length function, to print the number of different keys in the hash/array?

Comment: If I understand the question you want the total unique keys, we can just add a counter and print it:  awk '{ map[$2] += $3 + $4; } END { for (i in map) { print "2", i, map[i] | "sort -t'n'"; cnt++; } print "total unique: " cnt }'  file

Comment: @taliezin Sorry, not the total unique but the occurrences of each key, e.g. 1019 - 2, 1021 - 2, 1022 - 1, etc.

Comment: It is almost the same: awk '{ map[$2] += $3 + $4; oc[$2]++; } END { for (i in map) { print "2", i, map[i], oc[i] | "sort -t'n'"; } }', now you will see another column with occurrences.

Comment: @taliezin Thanks again! oc[$2]++ was what I was looking for. This forum is really a killer!

Answer (score 4):

You could pre-sort the data and let awk handle the details:

```
sort -n infile | awk 'NR>1 && p!=$2 {print p,s} {s+=$3+$4} {p=$2}'
```

You may want to reset the accumulator:

```
sort -n infile | awk 'NR>1 && p!=$2 {print p,s;s=0} {s+=$3+$4} {p=$2}'
```

Output:

```
1019 15
1021 19
1022 28
1030 34
```

If you really want the keep the first column, do something like this:

```
sort -n infile | awk 'NR>1 && p!=$1FS$2 {print p,s} {s+=$3+$4} {p=$1FS$2}'
```

Output:

```
2 1019 15
2 1021 19
2 1022 28
2 1030 34
```

#### Explanation

The `p` variable holds the `$2` value of the previous line, or `$1FS$2` in the second case above. This means that the `{print p,s}` is triggered when `$2` of the previous line is not the same as the one on the current line (`p!=$2`).

Comment: note that even if the first column had different values you could use ```sort -k2``` to sort by the second column

Answer (score 2):

Using swiss army knife util [`mlr`](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller):

```
mlr --nidx   put '$5=$3+$4'   then   stats1 -g 1,2 -f 5 -a sum   infile
```

Output:

```
2   1019    15
2   1021    4
2   1022    9
2   1030    6
2   1031    8
```

---

Notes:

- `--nidx` tells `mlr` to use numeric field names.
- `put '$5=$3+$4'` makes a new *5th* field, the sum of fields *3* and *4*.
- The `stats1` function (or "*verb*") is a smaller swiss army knife
  within the greater swiss army knife of `mlr`, with several
  accumulator based functions such as `sum`, `count`, `mean`, *etc.*

  `stats1 -g 1,2` groups the data by columns *1* and *2*,    and `-f 5
  -a sum` then adds up those groups' field *5*.  `stats1`    prints named fields only.