# Count & sum no. of occurrences of each unique line in a file

Tags: uniq

I think the answer to this problem might be some sort of variant of the `uniq` function that allows you to count the number of times each line appears in a file:

```
sort file.txt | uniq -c
```

The problem for me is that I have used this `uniq` function to generate a line count, and because I am merging the output with other files, I end up with duplicate lines in the file that need further rationalisation.

For example, with the original `uniq` line count at the beginning of each line:

```
34 banana

23 apple

48 grapefruit

23 banana

12 apple
```

So what I need to get to is:

```
57 banana

35 apple

48 grapefruit
```

Is there some function that will `SUM` on the first field, in all cases where the remaining field(s) are identical?

Answer (score 11):

An `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '{i[$2]+=$1} END{for(x in i){print i[x]" "x}}' file.txt
35 apple
48 grapefruit
57 banana
```

First `awk` makes an array whose index is the name (banana, apple, grapefruit) and sums up the values in the first column. At the end that array is printed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

my %count_of;

while ( <> ) {
   my ( $word) = m/(\w+)/;
   $count_of{$word}++;
}

foreach my $word ( sort { $count_of{$a} <=> $count_of{$b} } keys %count_of ) {
    print "$count_of{$word} $word\n";
}
```

Run it with `perl script.pl file1 file2 file3 file4`.

Alternatively - you probably want to just use cat.

```
cat file1 file2 file3 | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Thanks (can't vote up sorry), and I just noticed duplicate question here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190947/sum-columns-based-on-matching-fields?rq=1